# Restful - Moxy doesn't make unmarshalling properly in weblogic 14c

Tags: java, rest, jersey, unmarshalling, moxy

I have a rest web service which consumes JAXB annotated nested object as input as well as produces JAXB annotated nested object.

You can think of my nested objects like;

```
{
    "propertyOne": "bla bla",
    "propertyTwo": "5",
    objectB: {
        "propertyA": "xyz",
        "propertyB": "true"
    }

}
```

And my resource definition for web service like;

```
    @POST
    @Path("/abc")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ObjectC search(ObjectA objectA) {
        // some logic
    }
```

This is a working structure with java1.8 on weblogic 12c. But after migration to java11 and weblogic 14c when I send a request to this web service I am receiving an empty objectA in my search resource like;

```
{
    "propertyOne": "",
    "propertyTwo": "",
    objectB: null
}
```

there is a unmarshalling problem, why is that? any idea...

NOT : library used from past I am using MOXY as JSON provider

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of Jersey does WebLogic 14 use? Moxy might not even be the default anymore. If you want to ensure Moxy is used, don't put it as provided and explicitly register the Moxy provider (or feature)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, thnx your reply. I removed moxy's scope and registered MoxyJsonFeature but now I getting an error; Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeatureAutoDiscoverable 
cannot be cast to class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable 
(org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeatureAutoDiscoverable is in unnamed module of loader 
weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader @1ac42b0d; org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable 
is in unnamed module of loader com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader @13e39c73)

Comment: If WebLogic has MOXy library already, you can probably put the scope back. Registering the feature should be enough to ensure MOXy is used. I think the error  might be due the different in Jersey version you are using in your application and the version of Jersey WebLogic has

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha, you are right, it was enough to register, it worked. I think weblogic keeps moxy libraries still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul's recommendation solved the issue, just put moxy in provided scope and register MoxyJsonFeature, it worked